# I try open files in directory and i have this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'john.txt'

Tags: python, listdir

test.py:

```
import os, sys

# Open a file
path = "C:/Users/mypc/Myapp/myapp/myfiles"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

for file in dirs:
    with open(file, 'rb') as _fp:
        fileData = _fp.read()
        print("FILE DATA (%s):\n\n%s\n\n"%(_fp.name, fileData))
```

my folder:

```
Myapp/
   myapp/
      myfiles/
              john.txt
              juma.txt
              fatma.txt
      test.py
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mypc/Myapp/myapp/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open(file, 'rb') as _fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'john.txt'
```

I tried to solved it but i didn't find th solution, i need help

Comment: You need to join the file name with the directory name: `os.path.join(path, file)`

Comment: I also assume you don't want `rb` for bytes, but just `open(os.path.join(path, file)) as _fp` (given that it's a txt file)

Comment: Doesn't windows use reverse \ for separating the file path?

Comment: @alec - Yes, because of a lazy decision years ago.  However Python (and proper OS’s) use the forward slash, as the backslash in actuality is an escape character.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not in the same directory you need the full path name to get the file. Here is what I would do. Add the path variable, a "/" , and file inside the open function. Better to use  open(os.path.join(path, file)).

```
import os, sys

# Open a file
path = "C:/Users/mypc/Myapp/myapp/myfiles"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

for file in dirs:
    with open( path + "/" + file) as _fp:
        fileData = _fp.read()
        print("FILE DATA (%s):\n\n%s\n\n"%(_fp.name, fileData))
```

Comment: It working, Thank you